# Java changing static variable in another class doesn't affect object value

Tags: java, static, libgdx

I have a variable `SCROLL_SPEED` that I want to change.

This variable is `static` and defined in the following class:

```
public class ScrollHandler {

    public static int SCROLL_SPEED = -57;
    public final int TOWER_GAP = 200;

    private GameWorld gameWorld;

    public ScrollHandler(GameWorld gameWorld, float yPos) {
        this.gameWorld = gameWorld;

        GameWorld.obstacle1 = new Obstacle(210, 0, 25, 0, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);
        GameWorld.obstacle2 = new Obstacle(GameWorld.obstacle1.getTailX() + TOWER_GAP, 0, 25, 0, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);
        GameWorld.obstacle3 = new Obstacle(GameWorld.obstacle2.getTailX() + TOWER_GAP, 0, 25, 0, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);
        GameWorld.obstacle4 = new Obstacle(GameWorld.obstacle3.getTailX() + TOWER_GAP, 0, 25, 0, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        // Update our objects
        GameWorld.obstacle1.update(delta);
        GameWorld.obstacle2.update(delta);
        GameWorld.obstacle3.update(delta);
        GameWorld.obstacle4.update(delta);

        // Check if any of the obstacles are scrolled left,
        // and reset accordingly
        if (GameWorld.obstacle1.isScrolledLeft()) {
            GameWorld.obstacle1.reset(GameWorld.obstacle4.getTailX() + TOWER_GAP);
        } else if (GameWorld.obstacle2.isScrolledLeft()) {
            GameWorld.obstacle2.reset(GameWorld.obstacle1.getTailX() + TOWER_GAP);
        } else if (GameWorld.obstacle3.isScrolledLeft()) {
            GameWorld.obstacle3.reset(GameWorld.obstacle2.getTailX() + TOWER_GAP);
        } else if (GameWorld.obstacle4.isScrolledLeft()) {
            GameWorld.obstacle4.reset(GameWorld.obstacle3.getTailX() + TOWER_GAP);
        }
    }
```

When I change `SCROLL_SPEED` normally to `public static int SCROLL_SPEED = -285`, it works perfectly fine.

But when I change `SCROLL_SPEED` from another class like the following, it doesn't work (the value is still the same):

```
try {
        turbomode = new Rectangle(GameWorld.obstacle2.getX() - GameRenderer.generator2.getValue2(),
                GameWorld.obstacle2.getY() + GameRenderer.generator2.getValue1(), 15, 15);
        if ((Intersector.overlaps(GameWorld.wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), turbomode))){
            GameRenderer.TurboModeActive = true;
            activeItem = true;
            case1 = true;
            if (activeItem){
                System.out.println("TEST 1");
                ScrollHandler.SCROLL_SPEED = -285;
            } else{
                ScrollHandler.SCROLL_SPEED = -57;
            }
            System.out.println("TEST 2");
            new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        public void run() {
                            GameRenderer.TurboModeActive = false; 
                            activeItem = false;
                            case1 = false;
                        }
                    },
                    8000
            );
        }
} catch (NullPointerException e){
    System.out.println("TEST 3");
}
```

I know that it goes through the if statement, because it prints out `TEST 1`, but I don't know why it does not work. Can someone tell me what the issue might be?

Comment: Have you tried some other method of  changing the value? Something like a static setter maybe, though I doubt it would solve the problem

Comment: As to why it always prints "TEST 1", `activeItem` is always true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a timing issue.

```
GameWorld.obstacle1 = new Obstacle(210, 0, 25, 0, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);
```

If you change `SCROLL_SPEED` after `obstacle1` has been created, that won't have any effect anymore. That obstacle already has its value.

So you need to find the obstacle instance and change its speed instance variable, or have the obstacle look at your static variable instead of its own variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the **SCROLL_SPEED** and affect all **Obstacle**, you just have to remove the **SCROLL_SPEED** from the **Obstacle** constructor and call directly **ScrollHandler.SCROLL_SPEED** from **Obstacle** when you need it.

So

`GameWorld.obstacle1 = new Obstacle(210, 0, 25, 0, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);`

become

`GameWorld.obstacle1 = new Obstacle(210, 0, 25, 0, yPos);`

and in Obstacle constructor call **ScrollHandler.SCROLL_SPEED**

Comment: If you look at `SCROLL_SPEED` in the Obstacle constructor, you get the exact same effect as now. Any changes afterwards won't be propagated.

Comment: You're right the point was to call ScrollHandler.SCROLL_SPEED when Obstacle or something else needs it... Otherwise that would mean using an Observable... more complex solution :)